# CPU or GPU have more influence on video editing experience?

Tags: cpu, gpu, video-editing, adobe-premiere

Which of the following system will brings better video editing experience?

1. Moderate CPU with Good GPU (dedicated graphic cards)
2. Good CPU with Moderate GPU (build-in graphics)

In other words, CPU or GPU will have more influence on video editing experience (not exporting) on the latest version of Adobe Premiere Pro?

Comment: What kind of video editing, and with what software. If they are tasks that can be parellelled and coded in the language of the GPU - and if the software supports it a GPU will outperform a CPU.

Comment: @davidgo Software to be used will be Adobe products such as Adobe Premiere Pro and After Effects.

Comment: "It depends" is about the best answer you are going to get. Different generations of hardware support different levels of hardware decoding and encoding, and workstation cards can support more concurrent streams. Then it is up to the software to support all the features. This is down to going to the software developer and them telling you what they support and the best options. This can't be definitively answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that question can be answered definitively without taking other things into account like the rendering algorithm for instance because CPUs and GPUs are utilized differently.

This article from Adobe may be of interest:

https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/scaling-in-premiere-pro-cs5/